# How do I set a the value variable string of a form from another from?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form1 I have a variable

```
public string parent;
```

and in my form2 I have the code to set that variable's value

```
 Form1 bfm = new Form1();

 bfm.ShowDialog(this);
 bfm.parent = "EditItem";
```

but when I used the variable parent it gives me a null reference exception

What could be the problem here? Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance. I am just a beginner.

Comment: You are using two different instances of `Form1`.

Comment: There must be 50 versions of this question on SO already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you...

Just create a Parent on the Form1 class and set it before you show Form1.

```
public class Form1
{
  ...
 public string Parent{ get; set; }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(this.Parent);
 }
}
```

From Form2:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string dName = "EditItem";
Form1 bfm= new Form1();
bfm.Parent= dName;
bfm.Show();
this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` is modal.  The assignment of `parent` doesn't occur until the the dialog is closed.  You need to do the assignment before calling `ShowDialog`.

```
var bfm = new Form1() { parent = "EditItem" };
bfm.ShowDialog(this);
```